# Polymorphic return type by using TypeTag in Scala

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors, type-systems

What I want to do is returning generics type in Scala function by using TypeTag. Here is the example code.

```
trait Parent[T]

object IntChild extends Parent[Int]
object StringChild extends Parent[String]

object SomeClass {
  def of[A: TypeTag]: Parent[T] = {
    getElementType[A] match {
      case Int => IntChild
      case String => StringChild
    }
  }
}

SomeClass.of[Array[Int]]
```

But it throws a compile error. Because the returned type of `of` method is not fixed in the compile type. Is there any way to get the type information from TypeTag and embed the type in the returned type?

What I am expecting is like

```
// T is inferred from TypeTag A.
def of[A: TypeTag, T]: Parent[T] = {
  //...
}
```

I found this code also has not passed compile. So we need to fix the type information inferred from A's TypeTag.

```
def of[A: TypeTag]: Parent[_] = {
  //...
}
```

This is the error.

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[Int]
[error]  required: Array[_$1]
```

How can I get the element type in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible with those definitions. How about changing the definitions a little?

```
trait Parent[T]

implicit object IntChild extends Parent[Int]
implicit object StringChild extends Parent[String]

object SomeClass {
  def of[A: Parent]: Parent[A] = implicitly
}
```

This makes sure everything is done at the type level so that you get the return type you want. It requires the `implicit` modifier on `IntChild` and `StringChild`. There's no need to have another type parameter named `T`, as it would always be the same as `A` in your example.

Comment: Actually, it works in my case. It was so helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Kai Sasaki If the answer has helped you, can you please accept it?